# How to setup a bridge on ubuntu with two NIC's - one for WAN and one for LAN, that are connected to MaaS

Tags: networking, server, maas

Hi we are two students with a bachelor project in a business where we are going to make a cloud using MaaS 2.5. Never used it before so alot of try and errors...

We are running ubuntu bionic 18.04 on our maas server. One NIC (eno1) is connected to our router with IP-address 192.168.0.100 (also my maas server) and the other (eno2) is connected to a switch with IP-address 10.0.0.1. We turned off the dhcp on the router and used the dhcp on the web ui instead (see screenshot). We have two machines we want to deploy (HP workstations)

MaaS will give the machines ip-address (we tried using both NIC's, one machine gets 192.168.0.110 and the other gets 10.0.0.100) but both is failing when try commissioning (because of timeout). We think a solution would be to make a bridge between the NIC with WAN and NIC with LAN to get the nodes to connect to a network. The BMC (Intel AMT) is working fine and we can turn the machines on and off in the web ui.

[image: our subnets]

The workstations have the correct time. amtterm, wsmancli, and etherwake is installed. Any help with would be very appreciated.

our `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` looks like this:

```
enter code hnetwork: 
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
 eno1:
  dhcp4: no
  addresses: [192.168.0.100/24]
  gateway4: 192.168.0.1
  nameservers:
   addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
 eno2:
  dhcp4: no
  addresses: [10.0.0.1/24]
  gateway4: 192.168.0.100
  nameservers:
   addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your network scheme correctly you have to config NAT on your maas server. But your netcfg shouldn't work because you can't set a gw address outside of network... (for eno2 you don't need to set gw and nameservers).

Setup NAT on MAAS with 2 network interfaces.
Enable forwarding in kernel, edit file and uncomment line net/ipv4/ip_forward=1

```
sudo nano /etc/ufw/sysctl.conf
net/ipv4/ip_forward=1
```

save and exit

In the file /etc/default/ufw change the parameter DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```

Add NAT to ufw’s configuration. Add the following to /etc/ufw/before.rules just before the filter rules.

```
# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Forward traffic through eno1
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.1/24 -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these nat table rules won't
# be processed
COMMIT
```

Accept ports needed for maas

```
sudo ufw allow 22    
sudo ufw allow 69
sudo ufw allow 5240
sudo ufw allow 5248
sudo ufw allow 8000
```

Now enable the changes by restarting ufw.

```
sudo ufw disable && sudo ufw enable
```

On MAAS you should config DHCP on eno2, and your nodes for commission should be connected via switch to that network.